# Is there a programmatic way to detect what region a Cloud Function runs in?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How can one detect the region of a Firebase project?

It looks like it's exposed at:

```
>>> firebase.app().services_.functions['[DEFAULT]'].region_ 
'us-central1'

>>> firebase.app().functions().region_
'us-central1'
```

This does not look to be part of the [public API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.functions.Functions)

Is the `region_` property something one can rely on?  Is there an API call that otherwise exposes it?